# WAR file deployment not connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, xampp, war

I made a dynamic web project in Eclipse IDE and generated a .war file to uploaded it on tomcat localhost for testing using XAMPP server

I deployed the war file in tomcat manager and all the pages are getting displayed properly.

I have made a few connections for connecting to mysql database for insertions. But the deployed does not  interacts with the XAMPP phpmyadmin

I checked the username and password for connection string in my java program and made changes in config.inc.php file accordingly in phpmyadmin folder

All the database operations are being executed inside the eclipse environment but when I deploy the war file it is not executing.

Comment: are both version running on same machine

Comment: Yes both are running on same machine

Comment: post your log or exception

Answer (score 0):

Check your XAMPP Apache server configuration.. 
Go to,  **config -> phpMyAdmin(config.inc.php)**  and check this username & password related to Your Java Program.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''
```

If Mysql has any different password, Change **root password** to empty.